# Code Division Multiple Access

Tags: networking, cdma

In CDMA,we usually obtain the result by the rules,

```
c1 * c2 = 0;
c1 * c1 = 4.
```

Can not we use the other constant no.?
What is the significance of **c1 * c1 =** ***4*** ?